# SOAP JBOSS java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss

When I try to deploy the web services it tells me that it can not find the class.

```html
17:39:15,305 GRAVE [com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.getImplementorClass:617] (MSC service thread 1-8) euo.bk.soap.impl.S_Impl_Prueba from [Module "deployment.euo.bk.soap.pd.war:main" from Service Module Loader]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: euo.bk.soap.impl.S_Impl_Prueba from [Module "deployment.euo.bk.soap.pd.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:615) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:256) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:152) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
 at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

17:39:15,317 GRAVE [com.sun.xml.ws.server.http.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate:138] (MSC service thread 1-8) WSSERVLET11: Fallo al analizar el descriptor en tiempo de ejecución: com.sun.xml.ws.util.exception.LocatableWebServiceException: No se ha encontrado la clase en el descriptor de tiempo de ejecución: euo.bk.soap.impl.S_Impl_Prueba.
en la línea 9 de jndi:/default-host/euo.bk.soap.pd/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml: com.sun.xml.ws.util.exception.LocatableWebServiceException: No se ha encontrado la clase en el descriptor de tiempo de ejecución: euo.bk.soap.impl.S_Impl_Prueba.
en la línea 9 de jndi:/default-host/euo.bk.soap.pd/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:618) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:256) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:179) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.parseAdaptersAndCreateDelegate(WSServletContextListener.java:131) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:152) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
 at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: euo.bk.soap.impl.S_Impl_Prueba from [Module "deployment.euo.bk.soap.pd.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
 at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules-1.1.1.GA.jar:1.1.1.GA]
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:615) [jaxws-rt.jar:2.2.8]
 ... 12 more
```

sun-jaxws.xml

The file sun-jaxws.xml has the correct path, as clicking with control takes you to the next class (which says it can not find)

```
<endpoints version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime">
  <endpoint name="pd_Prueba_WSDL" implementation="euo.bk.soap.impl.S_Impl_Prueba" url-pattern="/pd_Prueba" />
```

```html
import javax.jws.WebService;
import euo.bk.soap.interf.S_Interf_Prueba;


@WebService
public class S_Impl_Prueba implements S_Interf_Prueba {

 @Override
 public String prueba(String txt) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return "prueba";
 }

      
 
}
```

If I execute commenting the line

Is executed correctly, but without the web service.

(I put the code with snippet, since it looked bette)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already been able to resolve the issue.

The error was in web.xml, because Randomly added xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
```

If you delete it and leave it this way, it works again.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
```